# How to use Windows credentials to auto login Azure Active Directory managed applications instead of Single Sign-On

Tags: single-sign-on, windows-authentication, azure-active-directory, autologin

After implementing the integration of Azure Active Directory and some other could applications like Salesforce, and syncing On-Premise Active Directory data by using Azure AD Connect, now I could auto login Salesforce and other cloud apps with Single Sign-On by using the credentials I used for desktop logon, but I still need to key in the credentials once when accessing Azure Applications page (Azure Portal).

Is there any configuration in Azure I can change to support auto-login by using the Windows credentials, so that once I log into my encrypted machine, I could auto login the Azure Applications page (the Azure portal) without key in password again? If Azure does not support no sign-on, what's the best way to do some development to support no sign-on?

Any post or suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to authorize users using Graph API. Maybe this will be helpfully: https://github.com/devkimchi/Graph-API-App-Only-Web-API-Sample

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using ADFS for federated identity and the following article helped, not sure if it applies to Azure AD Connect but it might give you some useful info.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2535227

Answer (score 0):

Thanks thedev and dawidr for your reply.

Finally I found a solution which might achieve the No Sign-On. AAD supports federation authentication, so just try to integrate the ADFS and AAD by using Azure AD Connect to implement the federation identify with On-Premise AD, then no more password key-in when accessing the Azure Applications. I don't have a proxy server with public IP so it's just a solution in my mind without verification.